# Way to replace one variable with another in a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to replace one variable with another variable in a multiple strings.
For example:

```
string1="One,two" 
string2="three.four" 
string3="five:six"
y=";"
for str in string1 string2 string3; do
    x="$(echo "$str" | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]//g')" # extracting a character between letters
    sed 's/$x/$y/'$str # I tried this, but it does not work at all.
    echo "$str"
done
```

Expecting output:

```
One;two
three;four
five;six
```

In my output, nothing changes:

```
One,two
three.four
five:six
```

Comment: what's the issue? please update the question with a) the (wrong) output generated by your code and b) the (correct) expected output

Comment: There's an extra `)` on the `string3` line.

Comment: Use the bash `${variable//old/new}` parameter expansion syntax rather than `sed`.

Comment: The second argument to `sed` is a filename, not a string.

Comment: @Barmar I tried running `${str//$x/$y}` and `${str//"$x"/"$y"}` and it does not work.

Comment: @Barmar Also I found the answer to similiar question with `sed` - changing `.` to `,` with numbers and I thought that it may also work with variables instead of constant value characters.

Comment: You're missing the `$` before variables in `for str in string1 string2 string3`

Comment: Using shell variables in `sed` substitutions is very tricky, and best avoided.  See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/4154375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bash's substitution operator instead of `sed`. And simply replace anything that isn't a letter with `$y`.

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="One,two"
string2="three.four"
string3="five:six"
y=";"

for str in "$string1" "$string2" "$string3"; do
    x=${str//[^a-zA-Z]+/$y}
    echo "$x"
done
```

Output is:

```
One;two
three;four
five;six
```

Note that your general approach wouldn't work if the input string has muliple delimiters, e.g. `One,two,three`. When you remove all the letters you get `,,`, but that doesn't appear anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing issues with OP's current code:

- referencing variables requires a leading `$`, preferably a pair of `{}`, and (usually) double quotes (eg, to insure embedded spaces are considered as part of the variable's value)
- `sed` can take as input a) a stream of text on stdin, b) a file, c) process substitution or d) a here-document/here-string
- when building a `sed` script that includes variable refences the `sed` script must be wrapped in double quotes (not single quotes)

Pulling all of this into OP's current code we get:

```
string1="One,two" 
string2="three.four" 
string3="five:six"
y=";"

for str in "${string1}" "${string2}" "${string3}"; do   # proper references of the 3x "stringX" variables
    x="$(echo "$str" | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]//g')"
    sed "s/$x/$y/" <<< "${str}"                         # feeding "str" as here-string to sed; allowing variables "x/y" to be expanded in the sed script
    echo "$str"
done
```

This generates:

```
One;two                 # generated by the 2nd sed call
One,two                 # generated by the echo
;hree.four              # generated by the 2nd sed call
three.four              # generated by the echo
five;six                # generated by the 2nd sed call
five:six                # generated by the echo
```

OK, so we're now getting some output but there are obviously some issues:

- the results of the 2nd `sed` call are being sent to stdout/terminal as opposed to being captured in a variable (presumably the `str` variable - per the follow-on `echo` ???)
- for `string2` we find that `x=.` which when plugged into the 2nd `sed` call becomes `sed "s/./;/"`; from here the `.` matches the first character it finds which in this case is the 1st `t` in `string2`, so the output becomes `;hree.four` (and the `.` is not replaced)
- dynamically building `sed` scripts without knowing what's in `x` (and `y`) becomes tricky without some additional coding; instead it's typically easier to use [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to perform the replacements for us
- in this particular case we can replace both `sed` calls with a single parameter substitution (which also eliminates the expensive overhead of two subprocesses for the `$(echo ... | sed ...)` call)

Making a few changes to OP's current code we can try:

```
string1="One,two" 
string2="three.four" 
string3="five:six"
y=";"

for str in "${string1}" "${string2}" "${string3}"; do
    x="${str//[^a-zA-Z]/${y}}"                          # parameter substitution; replace everything *but* a letter with the contents of variable "y"
    echo "${str} => ${x}"                               # display old and new strings
done
```

This generates:

```
One,two => One;two
three.four => three;four
five:six => five;six
```

Comment: "preferably a pair of {}" Where have you heard this preference, I almost never see the `{}` unless the variable followed by alphanumerics and you need to delimit it.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer and clarification of all the errors.

Comment: I think most people find `"$foo"` just as readable as `"${foo}"`